# Display diff output side-by-side

Tags: ediff

I use the version control system [fossil](http://fossil-scm.org). I'd like to view `fossil diff`'s output side-by-side in Emacs. The output looks like this:

```
$ fossil diff
Index: test1.txt
==================================================================
--- test1.txt
+++ test1.txt
@@ -1,1 +1,1 @@
-Old text
+New text

Index: test2.txt
==================================================================
--- test2.txt
+++ test2.txt
@@ -1,1 +1,1 @@
-Old text 2
+New text 2
```

Is there a way to display this output side-by-side, perhaps with ediff?

Comment: @ChillarAnand Yes, it colors the text but it doesn't display it side-by-side.

Comment: Do you want to see the original files, or just the parts that are covered by the diff?

Comment: @Gilles Only the parts covered by the `fossil diff` output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with the diffview package: https://github.com/emacsmirror/diffview

configuration

`(require 'diffview)`

execution

`M-x diffview-current`